# No more mobile devices for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

No more mobile devices for ubuntu?

Look at here https://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id=1088328531280217

> Artur Szczerba: Where/when can I buy meiu with ubuntu os?
>
> MEIZU Hi Artur, we no longer offer Ubuntu with our devices.

And on the ubuntu page all devices sold out already 6 months!

Comment: off-topic for this sitte

Comment: It's not off topic. The question is related to UBUNTU!

Comment: I want to buy ubuntu phone, but it exist not! Already a half of year!

Comment: but this is about **buying** a Ubuntu phone.

Comment: And yes, where to buy, when are new (or old) devices coming? No information overall in internet! Therfore I asked, may be somebody known about mobile production progress, how long wait? I waited half year on meizu 6 ubuntu, and now "no longer offer"

Comment: We, specifically, don't develop Ubuntu Touch, and really can't point out specific devices. However, there aren't any current devices being sold that run Ubuntu Touch. Furthermore, it really isn't a great mobile OS.

Comment: I can see that this could be classed as off topic for the forum as this is reläted to hardware and therefore something people here may not be able to answer. However, when you click on 'Ubuntu Help' from your phone you are directed here. People could be forgiven for thinking this aite may be able to help with hardware too.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking on the site and it says they are out of stock. If you look on the Ubuntu Devices page they say that “all our devices are currently sold out, but new devices will be coming soon”. So we can only hope that they will be here soon. If you sign up to the Devices Newsletter on this page you will get a clear idea of what is out there when it is released, Ubuntu Device. Email BQ from their Contacts email address and ask them.

Comment: Pity that BQ has low-level devices, only one high-level was meizu pro 5, but sold out too

Comment: That is true and it is a shame that all are sold out. The bq M10 is nice though and is showing good signs. We should not have a go at bq too much though as they were willing to give Ubuntu  Touch a go though.